# Display google calendar on Android calendarView widget?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, calendarview

My question is simple, is there a way to display a Google Calendar using Android calendarView inside an application? I can't find a way to do so

Comment: what do you mean "google calendar"?

Answer (score 8):

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Introducing ICS Calendar"
android:gravity="center"
 android:padding="10dip"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/data"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:padding="10dip"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:gravity="center" >
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/previous"
 android:text="Prev"
 android:padding="10dip"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/next"
 android:text="Next"
 android:padding="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
import java.text.Format;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Cursor mCursor = null;
private static final String[] COLS = new String[]
{ CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART};
}
```

Now we need to override the on create method. Pay special attention to how we populate the database cursor. This is where we need our previously defined COLS constant. You’ll note also that after the database cursor is initialized and the click handler callbacks are set, we go ahead and manually invoke the on click handler. This shortcut allows us to initially fill out our UI without having to repeat code.

Main.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, null);
mCursor.moveToFirst();
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
onClick(findViewById(R.id.previous));
}
```

In our callback, we will manipulate the cursor to the correct entry in the database and update the UI.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
String title = "N/A";
Long start = 0L;
switch(v.getId()) {
case R.id.next:
if(!mCursor.isLast()) mCursor.moveToNext();
break;
case R.id.previous:
if(!mCursor.isFirst()) mCursor.moveToPrevious();
break;
}
Format df = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
Format tf = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);
try {
title = mCursor.getString(0);
start = mCursor.getLong(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
//ignore
}
tv.setText(title+" on "+df.format(start)+" at "+tf.format(start));
}
```

permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
```

Comment: Ok, solved that with the @TargetApi(14). But now I have no calendar on the simulator to know if this works... :)

Comment: Excellent, is there any way to make it look like a calendar? Currently it's just fetching the events.