# Populate Android CalendarView with google calendar events

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, calendarview

I've been looking up around here and haven't found anything nearly helpful so needed to open this post to ask the question.

Is it possible to "populate" (in simple words: fill) a CalendarView in android with the time-events present in a google calendar account? and display them in the calendar view. e.g., as when you sync your google calendar events with your phone's calendar app.

The target solution: **graphic** *(to show the events over the calendar-gui per day... just as a 30 days calendar looks like)*

One google account's "public" calendar to be seen from the app.

Working with SDK 26
BuildTools 26.0.2
AndroidStudio 3.1

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display google calendar on Android calendarView widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959592/display-google-calendar-on-android-calendarview-widget)

Comment: Thanks for the link, 2 main drawbacks: 1. only fetches calendar events (in text) from the personal calendar (I need to insert the google account-not a private one). 2. The post and code are from 2012 (target sdk 14). The solution I'm looking for is graphic. Thanks a lot for your comment Mr. Rebot